# Append a row using a single parameter received from POST request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I have a discord bot, that sends a POST request to a google sheet script, the POST request is made successfully, and it passes a single parameter named "text" which has a single line of text as content.

I need the script to add that content to a new row.

I have got the script to accept the POST request but instead of inserting the content of the parameter it just inserts "undefined".

Google Script:

```
function doPost(e) {
var o = e.params;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(e.params[text]);
}
```

Post Request being sent:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!test"))
  axios.post('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwRmVu2yXTN7OISG7SCTYTb8boKAwEpSbq-TxAw0MXMPs_6gg8j/exec', {
    params: {
      text: "This is the content to insert",
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Welcome. Well, that sounds like a problem with `e.params[text]`. I suggest some troubleshooting: after "var o = ...", insert this line `Logger.log("the parameter text = "+e.params[text]);`. Run the code and then View the Log and see the value of "e.params[text]".

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

- `params` is not a defined `key` in the provided event object `e`.
- Variable `test` is not defined.
- `appendRow` doesn't accept a string argument

#### Solution:

- `parameters`/`parameter` are the valid keys in `e`
- `test` should be quoted, if used as a literal key in bracket notation.
- Provide `test` as a single element in a `array` to `appendRow` method

#### Snippet:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([e.parameter["text"]]);
```

#### References:

- [Web app § Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)
- [Sheet#appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))